# Does $$ work to get the value of a variable that is being iterated over?

Tags: bash, shell

I want this program to work for any number of arguments, so I am using a for loop to iterate over them. How can I get the value?

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
arr=($(head -n1 file.csv| sed 's/,/ /g'))
for args in $(seq 1 $#)
do
  >> for OUTPUT in "${arr[@]}"
  do 
         if [ $OUTPUT = "${args[@]}" ]
         then
            echo $((count +1))
         else 
            count = $((count+1))
         fi
   done
   count=0
 done
```

On the line where I put the >>, it only substitutes the number. If I put $@ it would just list all of the arguments.

Comment: Thank you! Also, count = $((count+1)) works perfectly

Comment: `IFS=, read -a arr < file.csv` would be more efficient, although it won't work any better than your original approach if any field in the first line can contain a comma.

Comment: `args` is not an array; it's just an individual argument. `[ "$OUTPUT" = "$args" ]`

Comment: How does the title of your question relate to anything in the actual question?

Comment: `count = $((count+1))` attempts to run the command `count` (which probably doesn't exist) with the arguments `=` and the value of the arithmetic expansion. If you want to assign a new value to the variable `count`, you mustn't have any whitespace on either side of the equals sign.

Comment: What do you hope for this code to actually do? There are no actual arguments. Do you mean you want to loop over a variable number of fields in the CSV file? How exactly does the current code fail to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for args in $(seq 1 $#)
```

Iterates over numbers 1 2 3 4 .... $#. You want to iterate over arguments. So do:

```
for args in "$@"
```

The `"$@"` willl expand to separated and properly escaped arguments.

```
if [ $OUTPUT = "${args[@]}" ]
```

The `args` is not an array, but a variable. Just

```
if [ "$OUTPUT" = "$args" ]
```

and remember to always quote your variables.